# Apache - reading/writing across vhost

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Is there a way for vhost X to write files to vhost Y? Here is my setup:

www.domain.com points to x.x.x.x IP address, using /httpdocs as directory
www.domain1.com points to x.x.x.x IP address, using /httpdocs/www.domain1.com as directory
www.domain2.com points to x.x.x.x IP address, using /httpdocs/www.domain2.com as directory

All websites are linked to the same database.

I would like that if a user uploads a file to domain1.com, the file is actually stored on domain2.com (/httpdocs/www.domain2.com/uploads). Is this possible?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Just set the upload dir (in your script) to "/httpdocs/www.domain2.com/uploads" (check the permissions if apache can write there), and upload the file there.

Comment: I have set the path, but I cannot 'see' the path. Using scandir (PHP) on /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/www.domain1.com/ shows true from domain1, and false from domain2.

I have also tried with just /httpdocs/www.domain1.com/ using full permissions (as a test) r/w/x. Still cannot see it.

Comment: I've figured it out. I added /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/www.domain2.com/ to the open_basedir for domain1.com

Thanks for your help anyway.